# Is there a way to have chunks of a page's content expire?

Tags: php, customization, the-content

I have a page on my site where I post items that have been discounted. However, each item's discount ends at a certain date. After that date, I don't want the item to be visible any longer. But I don't want to update the page every single day. Is there a way that WordPress can auto-remove a chunk of content that is within a tag?

Or maybe it would be better to create a custom post type and display the link to the posts on this page and then have the custom post type set to expire somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind wrapping your content in [`Shortcode`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) then you can easily have them hidden after a specific time. Granted you don't cache the page for longer than needed.

Wrap your content in `[content_expires]` shortcodes. Time should be based on your server's timezone.

```
[content_expires]NEVER Expires[/content_expires]

[content_expires date='2016-10-25 00:00:00']PAST[/content_expires]

[content_expires date='2116-10-26 04:20:00']FUTURE[/content_expires]
```

Then add the shortcode handler.

```
function content_expires__shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {

    $a = shortcode_atts( array (
        'date' => '', // "2010-01-21 00:00:00"
    ), $atts );

    // expires date
    $date = $a[ 'date' ];

    // not set, so we're fine
    if ( empty( $date ) ) {
        return $content;
    }

    // today's date
    $today = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s" );

    // only future time is allow. In the past will not be returned.
    return $date > $today ? $content : '';
}

add_shortcode( 'content_expires', 'content_expires__shortcode' );
```

Now content will only be rendered if it hasn't reached the date specified.